# Zsh completion duplicates folder names

Tags: zsh

I'm seeing a strange problem when completing folders with zsh 5.0.2 (and oh-my-zsh). When I go to tab complete folder names for a relative path, the folder names often duplicate and lose colour highlighting. It's frustrating as I then have to tab complete through each directory twice to get to the one I want.

It only happens if what I'm completing from finishes with a "/" so for example, "dev/" or "dev/code/" would cause the problem, but "dev/c" would not. Also the problem doesn't seem to happen for absolute paths "/home/dave/dev/" is fine.

I've attached an animation showing the problem below:

[image: Duplicating completion]

I don't have anything particularly fancy in my zsh config (which is here: https://github.com/actionshrimp/dotfiles/blob/master/zshrc)

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: purging `oh-my-zsh` would be a good first step. removing each of those 'plugins' one by one and see if it goes away is another way of checking. If it still happens, then start removing the `source` lines.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried turning off the plugins but no use. Definitely seems to be an oh-my-zsh issue, I finally managed to hunt this down on the issue tracker on github: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/1028